# Rails capistrano set deploy.rb variables based on user logged in to computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, capistrano

I'm working on a project with multiple developers and currently we have to change the variables in our deploy.rb script depending on who's computer we're deploying from.

How can we set the username and path/to/project depending on which computer we're on?

We're all running on osx.

Example

```
if osx logged in user == "jeff"
  set :user, "jeff's username'
else if ...
  set :user, 'blah'
end
```

How can i do this in rails/capistrano/osx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The os/x shell sets an env variable `$USER` that has the logged in user's login name. You can reference that as `ENV['USER']` in your cap files

Answer (score 1):

The `whoami` command should be available on most Unix systems, so the following should also work on Linux, etc.:

```
if `whoami` == "jeff"
  set :user, "jeff's username'
elsif ...
  set :user, 'blah'
end
```

Comment: this should be `if/elsif/end` instead of `if/else if/end`

Answer (score 1):

This is where environment variables come in handy.

```
set :user, ENV['USERNAME']
```

There are many ways to set this. You can do it directly in shell with

```
export USERNAME=blah
```

But for a cleaner, per-project solution I like the [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem. With this enabled in `:development` group of your `Gemfile`, when Rails loads, it will export each line of a special `.env` file in the root of your application as environment variables.

```
USERNAME=blah
```